# Kafka 1.x Obsolete Vulnerability

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j

All of us know, Kafka is still using log4j 1.x jar files even though Log4j 1.x has reached End of Life in 2015 and is no longer supported. So it became obsolete vulnerability for Kafka.

Are there any ways to replace log4j 1.x in present Kafka (docker images) or Is there any development work is going on to replace these log4j1.x? If yes, is there any ETA provided by Kafka team?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is active work to replace log4j, if not already done so. Please search Kafka JIRA.

Also refer to Kafka CVE list - https://kafka.apache.org/cve-list

And Confluent's own announcements - https://support.confluent.io/hc/en-us/articles/4412615410580-December-2021-Log4j-Vulnerabilities-Advisory

Regarding out of support versions of Kafka, that you're not willing to upgrade, then you can try replacing log4j directly with reload4j (I've not tried it), but of course, this will not handle nested dependencies very accurately.